# Is there a class of Application that combines MQTT and a RDMBS?

Tags: database

I am planning to install Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi substitute (Libre lePotato):
https://hub.libre.computer/t/ubuntu-server-vs-desktop-vs-base/2218

The goal is to setup a portable MQTT server that stores data in a relational-database.

Mosquitto can be setup with the [snap procedure](https://snapcraft.io/mosquitto).

mySQL can be setup with the [snap procedure](https://snapcraft.io/mysql).

I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel: Is there an application that bundles MQTT and RDBMS?